# graph rerouting algorithm hacker rank

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have tried to solve the problem Rerouting at hacker rank. I am posting here for help as competition is over.

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hack-the-interview-v-asia-pacific/challenges/rerouting

I have tried to solve problem using Strong connected components, but test cases failed. I can understand we have to remove cycles. But I stuck how to approach problem. Below is solution i have written. I am looking for guidence how to move forward so that i can apply my knowledge future based on mistakes i made here.  Thanks for your time and help

```
int getMinConnectionChange(vector<int> connection) {
    
    // Idea: Get number of strongly connected components.
    int numberOfVertices = connection.size();
    for(int idx = 0; idx < numberOfVertices; idx++) {
        cout << idx+1 <<":"<< connection[idx] << endl;
    }
    stack<int> stkVertices; 
    map<int, bool> mpVertexVisited; //is vertex visited.think this as a chalk mark for nodes visited.
    
    
    int numOFSCCs = 0;
    int currTime = 1;
    for (int vertexId = 0; vertexId < numberOfVertices; vertexId++) {
        // check if node is already visited.
        if (mpVertexVisited.find(vertexId+1) == mpVertexVisited.end()) {
            numOFSCCs++;
            mpVertexVisited.insert(make_pair(vertexId+1, true));
            stkVertices.push(vertexId+1);
            currTime++;

            while (!stkVertices.empty()) {
                int iCurrentVertex = stkVertices.top();
                stkVertices.pop(); 
                // get adjacent vertices. In this excercise we have only one neighbour. i.e., edge
                int neighbourVertexId = connection[iCurrentVertex-1];
                // if vertex is already visisted, don't insert in to stack.
                if (mpVertexVisited.find(neighbourVertexId) != mpVertexVisited.end()) {
                    continue;
                }
                mpVertexVisited.insert(make_pair(neighbourVertexId, true));
                stkVertices.push(neighbourVertexId);            
            } // while loop
        } // if condition m_mapVrtxTimes.find(*itr) == m_mapVrtxTimes.end()
    } // for loop of vertices
    return numOFSCCs - 1;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that I just solved and would like to share the solution.

The problem can be solved with union-find.

Two main observation:

1. The number of edges that has to be changed is the `number of components - 1` (not necessarily strongly connected) `Thus, union-find is handy here for finding the number of components`
2. Second observation is that some component doesn't have terminating node, consider `1<->2`, in other words, a cycle exist. We can detect whether there exists a terminating node if some node doesn't have an outgoing edge.

If all components have a cycle, it means that we need to change every component instead of `a number of components - 1`. This is to make it such that the graph will have a terminating point.

Code:

```
struct UF {
    vector<int> p, rank, size;
    int cnt;
    UF(int N) {
        p = rank = size = vector<int>(N, 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) p[i] = i;
        cnt = N;
    }
    int find(int i) {
        return p[i] == i ? i : p[i] = find(p[i]);
    }
    bool connected(int i, int j) {
        return find(i) == find(j);
    }
    void join(int i, int j) {
        if (connected(i, j)) return;
        int x = find(i), y = find(j);
        cnt--;
        if (rank[x] > rank[y]) {
            p[y] = x;
            size[x] += size[y];
        } else {
            p[x] = y;
            size[y] += size[x];
            if (rank[x] == rank[y]) rank[y]++;
        }
    }
};

int getMinConnectionChange(vector<int> connection) {
    int nonCycle = 0;
    int n = connection.size();
    UF uf(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
        int to = connection[i] - 1;
        if(to == i) nonCycle++;
        else uf.join(i, to);
    }
    int components = uf.cnt;
    int countCycle = uf.cnt - nonCycle;
    int res = components - 1;
    if(countCycle == components) res++; // all components have cycle
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR: you can view this as looking for a [minimal spanning arborescence problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree).

More precisely, add a node for each server, and another one called "Terminate".
Make a complete graph (each node is linked to every other one) and set as cost 0 for the edges corresponding to your input, 1 for the other ones.

You can use for example [Edmond's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonds%27_algorithm) to solve this.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. What does TL, DR mean here

Comment: if possible can you please elaborate. Thanks